# Google Map (GMap) resets height and width on IE7

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-7

I am setting multiple markers on google map and includes infoWindow content, it works perfect on FF, GC, IE9,8

But in IE7 the map becomes small (40px x 30px)

Following is my `<div>`

```
    <div id="listing-map-view" style="width:610px;height:380px;">

</div>
```

Following is the GmapCall

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map;
var userinput = "40.860294,-73.183374";
var latlong = userinput.split(",");
var lat = latlong[0];
var long = latlong[1];

$(document).ready(function(){
   map = new GMaps({
     div: '#listing-map-view',
     lat: lat,
     lng: long
   });

bounds.extend (new google.maps.LatLng (lat ,long));
map.addMarker({
lat: lat,
lng: long,
infoWindow: {content: 'Some Test Content'},
zoom:10,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a position relative bug fixed by adding following styles

```
/*Google Map Fixes for IE */

  #listing-map-view{
    z-index: 1000!important;  /*Outer DIV*/
    position:relative!important;
    width:610px!important;
    height:375px!important;
    padding: 0 15px!important;;
  }
  #listing-map-view > div{
    z-index: 500!important;   /*Actual DIV with the map*/
    position:absolute!important;
  }
```